# java.lang.NullPointerException and I can't figure out why

Tags: android

```
package com.nicotera.colton.londontransitguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class RoutesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.route_name_spinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default 
        // spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.routes_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        );

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
        );

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
12-06 23:34:28.954: E/AndroidRuntime(765): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 23:34:28.954: E/AndroidRuntime(765): at com.nicotera.colton.londontransitguide.RoutesActivity.onCreate(RoutesActivity.java:22)
```

So it appears the problem is on line 22, but I can't figure out exactly what is wrong?  I'm a brand new developer, so thaks for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess that line 22 is :

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Which implies that spinner is null.  Therefore, the call findViewById() is returning a null.  Check your layout, do you have a spinner with an ID "R.id.route_name_spinner" ?

Comment: I can answer that, no. `setContentView()` isn't used.

Comment: Yes, I have a spinner named route_name_spinner.
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/route_name_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: Thanks, guess I forgot that.  Again, I'm just beginning, so thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the explanation. What I think:

- You did not make a setContentView(R.layout.blablablabla)
- So the findViewById return null
- Finally you try to access the method setAdapter of your spinner which is null.

Serge

Answer (score 0):

Small change:
    setContentView(main.xml);

Comment: You need to use the resource id from the R file: `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.